# Negative limiter MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

My code get the last 10 values from a table. This table has te structure `id`,`text` and by the moment it has 20 rows. I use this piece of code

```
<?php
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 10");
// Fetching data stuff here
?>
```

and it returns the data for IDs 11-20. (The last 10 of the 20)

I want to get the previous 10 values from this 1-10 via AJAX. I thought maybe this will work

```
$previous_id= $_GET["last"];  // This time it will be 11
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT $previous_id, -10");
```

But I'm doesn't, any suggestion?

Thanks

**PS: This is not a `gimme teh codez` question, I just want to know how to make that query work.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want to get the 10 rows before the row with `id = $previous_id`, ordered by descending ID.

If that's the case your best bet would be to use a `WHERE` condition.  As you are ordering by `id DESC` you want the first 10 rows with `id > $previous_id`:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `id` > $previous_id ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 10
```

These will be the 10 rows before `$previous_id` in your original query.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use positive number instead of `-10`:

```
"SELECT * FROM `table` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT $previous_id, 10"
```

Let's suppose `$previous_id` is `5`, the query would be:

```
"SELECT * FROM `table` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 5, 10"
```

The returned rows will be starting from `5` and `10` records.

Comment: No men, I already have 11-20, i want 1-10. If I use `"SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $previous_id, 10"` (WHERE `$previous_id == "11"`) it will return  the 11-21 values.

Comment: `LIMIT 10` will give you 1 to 10.